# Tab bar disappears after touching cell in tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, ios5

I have an issue with a tab bar app. I am making a tab bar app with three bars on the bottom. On my my first bar it is a tableviewcontroller. When i ckick on the table view controller it takes me to a different view (which doesn't have the tab bar). When I clicked back to the home screen (which has the tab) the tab bar is gone.If you need a picture i will post it!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how your segues and storyboard is setup but I would guess that the view that is segued to when a cell is tapped doesn't have a tab bar and the tab bar is only part of your initial view contoller. Could you post some pictures, some code, and maybe a screenshot of your storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have set your `UITableViewController` segue to a modal style. If this is the case, you should change it to a push style.

In order for a push to work, your view controller needs to be in a `UINavigationController`. In your story board, select your root view controller and embed it into a Navigation Controller like this...

[image]

Comment: My segue is set to modal style. I did change it to push but it doesn't do anything (I clicked and it doesn't go to the view that was connect to in onthe segue:(